# Laravel 5 group by display only first row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

I have this in my controller.

```
> $getNetworkImages = DB::table('network_images')->groupBy('network_album')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

But this returns only first row, ordered by id(desc) of every album. I want all images in this album, not just first row.

My Eloquent is:

```
> @foreach($network_images as $album)
>   <div>
>       <a style="font-weight: 400;">{{ $album->network_author }}</a> създаде нов албум <a>{{ $album->network_album }}</a> преди <time
> class="timeago" datetime="{{ $album->network_created }}">{{ $album->network_created }}</time>.
>       <br />
>       {{ $album->network_text }}
>       <br />
>       <br />
>       {{ $album->network_images }}
>   </div>
>   <br />
> @endforeach
```

I cannot understand where is my mistake.

```
id | network_image | network_album
--------------------------------------------
1  |         123           |             1
2  |         456           |             1
3  |         789           |             2
4  |         101           |             2
```

Output:

*Network_album **1** contains network_image **123**.

Network_album **1** contains network_image **456**.

Network_album **2** contains network_image **789**.

Network_album **2** contains network_image **101**.*

I want:

*Network_album **1** contains network_image(s) **123** and **456**.

Network_album **2** contains network_image(s) **789** and **101**.*

Comment: If the `network_album` column has the same value across all rows, `groupBy()` would only return one value.

Comment: I edited my first post with output and what should output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby() groups the result-set by one or more columns.

If you're seeing only one row, that means all images belong to the same network_album.

If you wish to see all images that belong to one particular album, use where() to fetch results using the album id.

Comment: I edited my first post with output and what should output.